# php-fpm keep children running, not complete request and got max children fast

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, request

I have node server and have 8 website on it, 2 of them has most of traffic, all website connected to cloudflare CDN with low security level

and set php-fpm pool for every website

one of them has only strange problem

sometimes its working fine, without any problem , and suddenly all child in php-fpm (hanged) and keep running always without finish the request , that make reach max.children fast and all requests on website not completed

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; FPM Configuration ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


pid = /usr/var/run/php-fpm.pid
error_log = /log/php-fpm.log
log_level = notice
emergency_restart_threshold = 20
emergency_restart_interval = 2m
process_control_timeout = 10s
daemonize = yes
rlimit_files = 300
rlimit_core = unlimited

[www]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen.owner = root
listen.group = root
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
user = nobody
group = nobody 
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 120 
pm.start_servers = 25
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 45
pm.max_requests = 500
pm.status_path = /fpm_status.php
ping.path = /ping
request_terminate_timeout = 15s
catch_workers_output = yes
env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
env[TMP] = /tmp
env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
env[TEMP] = /tmp
env[TEMP] = /tmp
env[OSTYPE] = $OSTYPE
env[MALLOC_CHECK_] = 2
env[MACHTYPE] = $MACHTYPE
php_admin_value[sendmail_path] = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 512M
php_admin_value[mysql.connect_timeout] = 30
php_admin_value[default_socket_timeout] = 30  

[site1.com]
user = site1
group = site1
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm-site1.sock
listen.owner = site1
listen.group = site1
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 120
pm.start_servers = 25
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 45
pm.max_requests = 500
chdir = /home/site1/public_html

[sub1.site1.com]
user = sub1site1
group = sub1site1
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm-sub1site1.sock
listen.owner = sub1site1
listen.group = sub1site1
pm = ondemand 
pm.max_children = 25
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 35
pm.max_requests = 1000
pm.status_path = /status
chdir = /home/sub1site1/public_html
```

both site1.com, and sub1.site1.com have almost the same trafic
but site1.com is working very smooth , and sub1.site1.com have that problem

from  sub1.site1.com/status

```
pool    sub1.site1.com
process manager ondemand
start time  23/Jun/2017:07:50:37 
start since 992
accepted conn   987
listen queue    0
max listen queue    0
listen queue len    0
idle processes  0
active processes    25
total processes 25
max active processes    25
max children reached    1
slow requests   0
```

and all child come in running status . and that request not completed , sometimes got 502 error

I try increase max children to 200, but also same problem

if I reboot the node server,
sub1.site1 working for 3-5 hours very good
after that , give me this strange error

number of connection on server when every thing is fine

```
# netstat -ant | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
1 established)
1 Foreign
3 SYN_RECV
32 LISTEN
205 TIME_WAIT
1142 ESTABLISHED
```

/var/log/message while problem present

```
Jun 23 06:14:26 server smartd[5739]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], 3 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors 
Jun 23 06:14:26 server smartd[5739]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], 3 Offline uncorrectable sectors 
Jun 23 06:14:26 server smartd[5739]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], 9 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors 
Jun 23 06:14:26 server smartd[5739]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], 9 Offline uncorrectable sectors 
Jun 23 07:28:23 server kernel: Firewall: *TCP6IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=54:04:a6:b8:6c:0e:84:c1:c1:76:a8:d5:86:dd SRC=2400:cb00:2048:0001:0000:0000:681c:1402 DST=2a01:04f8:0160:1311:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=72 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=59 FLOWLBL=639020 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=5908 WINDOW=24400 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
Jun 23 07:28:25 server kernel: Firewall: *TCP6IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=54:04:a6:b8:6c:0e:84:c1:c1:76:a8:d5:86:dd SRC=2400:cb00:2048:0001:0000:0000:681f:4591 DST=2a01:04f8:0160:1311:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=72 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=60 FLOWLBL=902306 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=1331 WINDOW=24400 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
Jun 23 07:28:27 server kernel: Firewall: *TCP6IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=54:04:a6:b8:6c:0e:84:c1:c1:76:a8:d5:86:dd SRC=2400:cb00:2048:0001:0000:0000:681f:4591 DST=2a01:04f8:0160:1311:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=72 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=59 FLOWLBL=453074 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=1301 WINDOW=24400 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
Jun 23 07:28:29 server kernel: Firewall: *TCP6IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=54:04:a6:b8:6c:0e:84:c1:c1:76:a8:d5:86:dd SRC=2400:cb00:2048:0001:0000:0000:681f:4591 DST=2a01:04f8:0160:1311:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=72 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=59 FLOWLBL=945434 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=1262 WINDOW=24400 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
Jun 23 07:28:31 server kernel: Firewall: *TCP6IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=54:04:a6:b8:6c:0e:84:c1:c1:76:a8:d5:86:dd SRC=2400:cb00:2048:0001:0000:0000:681f:4591 DST=2a01:04f8:0160:1311:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=72 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=59 FLOWLBL=789301 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=1265 WINDOW=24400 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
Jun 23 07:28:33 server kernel: Firewall: *TCP6IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=54:04:a6:b8:6c:0e:84:c1:c1:76:a8:d5:86:dd SRC=2400:cb00:2048:0001:0000:0000:681f:4591 DST=2a01:04f8:0160:1311:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=72 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=60 FLOWLBL=87019 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=1314 WINDOW=24400 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
Jun 23 07:28:35 server kernel: Firewall: *TCP6IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=54:04:a6:b8:6c:0e:84:c1:c1:76:a8:d5:86:dd SRC=2a03:2880:f027:0013:face:b00c:0000:0002 DST=2a01:04f8:0160:1311:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=80 TC=140 HOPLIMIT=54 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=2348 WINDOW=27960 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
Jun 23 07:28:37 server kernel: Firewall: *TCP6IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=54:04:a6:b8:6c:0e:84:c1:c1:76:a8:d5:86:dd SRC=2400:cb00:2048:0001:0000:0000:681f:4591 DST=2a01:04f8:0160:1311:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=72 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=59 FLOWLBL=846096 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=1274 WINDOW=24400 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
Jun 23 07:28:39 server kernel: Firewall: *TCP6IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=54:04:a6:b8:6c:0e:84:c1:c1:76:a8:d5:86:dd SRC=2400:cb00:2048:0001:0000:0000:681f:4591 DST=2a01:04f8:0160:1311:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=72 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=60 FLOWLBL=164043 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=1338 WINDOW=24400 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
Jun 23 07:28:41 server kernel: Firewall: *TCP6IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=54:04:a6:b8:6c:0e:84:c1:c1:76:a8:d5:86:dd SRC=2400:cb00:2048:0001:0000:0000:681f:4591 DST=2a01:04f8:0160:1311:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=72 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=59 FLOWLBL=486686 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=1277 WINDOW=24400 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
Jun 23 07:28:43 server kernel: Firewall: *TCP6IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=54:04:a6:b8:6c:0e:84:c1:c1:76:a8:d5:86:dd SRC=2400:cb00:2048:0001:0000:0000:681f:4591 DST=2a01:04f8:0160:1311:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=72 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=60 FLOWLBL=63456 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=1344 WINDOW=24400 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
Jun 23 07:28:45 server kernel: Firewall: *TCP6IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=54:04:a6:b8:6c:0e:84:c1:c1:76:a8:d5:86:dd SRC=2400:cb00:2048:0001:0000:0000:681f:4591 DST=2a01:04f8:0160:1311:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=72 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=60 FLOWLBL=502407 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=1341 WINDOW=24400 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
Jun 23 07:28:47 server kernel: Firewall: *TCP6IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=54:04:a6:b8:6c:0e:84:c1:c1:76:a8:d5:86:dd SRC=2400:cb00:2048:0001:0000:0000:681c:1402 DST=2a01:04f8:0160:1311:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=72 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=59 FLOWLBL=286658 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=5908 WINDOW=24400 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
Jun 23 07:28:49 server kernel: Firewall: *TCP6IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=54:04:a6:b8:6c:0e:84:c1:c1:76:a8:d5:86:dd SRC=2400:cb00:2048:0001:0000:0000:681f:4591 DST=2a01:04f8:0160:1311:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=72 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=59 FLOWLBL=896418 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=1350 WINDOW=24400 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
Jun 23 07:28:51 server kernel: Firewall: *TCP6IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=54:04:a6:b8:6c:0e:84:c1:c1:76:a8:d5:86:dd SRC=2400:cb00:2048:0001:0000:0000:681f:4591 DST=2a01:04f8:0160:1311:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=72 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=60 FLOWLBL=441585 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=1341 WINDOW=24400 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
Jun 23 07:28:53 server kernel: Firewall: *TCP6IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=54:04:a6:b8:6c:0e:84:c1:c1:76:a8:d5:86:dd SRC=2400:cb00:2048:0001:0000:0000:681f:4591 DST=2a01:04f8:0160:1311:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=72 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=60 FLOWLBL=312546 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=1356 WINDOW=24400 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
Jun 23 07:28:55 server kernel: Firewall: *TCP6IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=54:04:a6:b8:6c:0e:84:c1:c1:76:a8:d5:86:dd SRC=2400:cb00:2048:0001:0000:0000:681f:4591 DST=2a01:04f8:0160:1311:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=72 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=59 FLOWLBL=462099 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=1310 WINDOW=24400 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
```

number of connection on server when problem happened

```
# netstat -ant | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
1 established)
1 Foreign
3 SYN_RECV
32 LISTEN
365 TIME_WAIT
1905 ESTABLISHED
```

load average all the time between 0.5 : 3.0

memory usage 2G:5G used / 16G total memory

also when check mysql  SHOW PROCESSLIST, give me 25 task in sleep command from sub1.site1 user database

why the php request sometime done without any delay, and after 5 hours from reboot the node , its delay too much and make more children created without complete the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your issues is that your hard disk on the server is broken:

```
Jun 23 06:14:26 server smartd[5739]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], 3 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors 
Jun 23 06:14:26 server smartd[5739]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], 3 Offline uncorrectable sectors 
Jun 23 06:14:26 server smartd[5739]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], 9 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors 
Jun 23 06:14:26 server smartd[5739]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], 9 Offline uncorrectable sectors
```

That is the most likely reason for the errors you are experiencing. Replace the hard disk and you should be fine.

Comment: I figure it out after posting, and  I prepare to change it, thanks for reply